# Retrieving records from many to many table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to retrieve notifications for a user. Some of the notifications will be general and for all users of the site. Other notifications are specific to a certain user when they do something specific.

Right now the records are adding fine My issue is detailed below:

User A: achieves new high score, notification is created.
User B: has not achieved new high score

When accessing the records User A's high score shows up in User B's notifications..

I am retrieving the notifications like so:

```
        public List<Notification> RetrieveAllNotifications(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var list = context.Notifications.ToList();
        var usernotif = user.Notifications.ToList();

        return usernotif.Union(list).OrderByDescending(d => d.Time).ToList();




        //var notifications = context.Notifications
        //                           .Include(n => n.ApplicationUser).ToList();

        //return notifications;
    }
```

As you can see there is a commented out line of code, these are other options I have tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: That's pretty logical that A's score shows in B's notifications since that's what union in LINQ does - it combines the lists together. From the code you've provided, looks like you can simply access user.Notifications. I suggest you try that instead of union. By the way, if for some reason you need to combine the lists, Intersect is a correct way to do that in your case, though I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: I have tried just to return User.Notifications, this gives me user specific notifications but does not return the other general notifications that every user should see. These are in the context.Notifications list

Comment: Do you have anything in the database that might answer the question 'is this notification general or specific to a user'? If not, the easiest way you can do that is to introduce the 'IsGeneral' boolean for notifications. Then you could Union user.Notifications and notifications.Where(notification => notification.IsGeneral). That's just a draft idea, but in the end you have to somehow distinguish general and specific notifications.

Comment: If I took that route I'd have a lot more records in my database I think. I was told it was appropriate to take this route.. Collection specific to the user and then just a general notifications table. I seen you mentioned intersect there above, could this be useful now?

Comment: Nope, Intersect won't help in that case. As to storing data, the approach you describe is pretty OK, I think. I've just misunderstood a bit and thought that context.Notifications holds all the notifications possible. If it holds only general ones, Union should work fine. Have you checked that context.Notifications has only general ones and not user specific? Judging from Union behaviour, looks like context.Notifications contains all the notifications in the system.

Comment: Yea you're right, looking at the database records context.Notifications contains all the records for the database even user specific ones. There is another table too called ApplicationUserNotification which holds the foreign key to the notification specific to another key for the user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141835/discussion-between-vlad-stryapko-and-gbear96).